# How to decode block extrinsics using Polkadot js api

Tags: polkadot-js

I am writing typescript code to get block information. I am connected to [wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io](http://wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io) . I am followig official polkadot js api [documentation](https://polkadot.js.org/api/substrate/rpc.html) .

I am calling **api.rpc.chain.getBlock** method get block information, and it returns block information as json :

```
{
  "header": {
    "parentHash": "0xf292579563eb2f12e7a1571643d5285a072f04694397758cae76b38075daf631",
    "number": 1134,
    "stateRoot": "0x468de0ef831c96f56d518017b18d76a89f35f30371c45866d12c12ca2116a407",
    "extrinsicsRoot": "0x4875f3ab89c2a3c30f5de8be2ac40cfaee02059fd69ea76115550a418db5fcc8",
    "digest": {
      "logs": [
        "0x066175726120d86ae01200000000",
        "0x05617572610101be3d6d596445d3cb3b711da09e22f9f24c283306744657ce397d17ff1dbf9859051def7406cd356b2d3d2add155d76618f6b098de0c4ce6b7620106ec00e1188"
      ]
    }
  },
  "extrinsics": [
    "0x280401000bc0ca26af7001"
  ]
}
```

How do I get extrinsic details as -

```
{
    "method": {
        "callIndex": "0x0200",
        "section":"timestamp",
        "method": "set",
        "args" : [
            "1,582,827,870,000"
        ]
    },
    "isSigned": false
}
```

I am assuming the extrinsic I am getting is encoded, what is the method to to decode it?

Answer (score 1):

I found `parseInt('0x33c395')` works great to decode block numbers

Answer (score 0):

Those are hex Uint8Array encoded.
If using node.js you could simply get rid of the "0x" string and perform a `Buffer.from(<U8A>, 'hex')`

Comment: Could you please give a more detailed example?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the extrinsic is `0x280401000bc0ca26af7001`
Let's decode. First comes the length of the extrinsic encoded by the `compact` encoding.

`0x28` is `0b00101000` i.e. the value is `0b001010` or `10` 10-base

`0x04` means that it is not signed extrinsic of the `4`th version (`EXTRINSIC_VERSION`), otherwise it would be `0b1000_0000 | EXTRINSIC_VERSION`
since it is not signed next comes `call_data`, otherwise there would be signature

`0x01` a runtime enum specific value (pallet_index)

`0x00` a runtime enum specific value (call_index)

`0x0bc0ca26af7001` according to the `compact` encoding the first byte `0x0b` ( `0b0000_1011` ) meas that it is the `big-integer` encoding according `0b11` two lower bits, the others `0b000010` are the number of the following bytes save the shift of `4`, i.e. the number of bytes is `4 + 0b10 = 6` in the LE encoding.
Thus one have to swap the `0xc0ca26af7001` bytes according to the byte-order.
`0xc0ca26af7001` -> `0x0170af26cac0` i.e. `1583486520000` 10-base